# Pipe results of bash script to a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having an issue with pipping the results from the below script to a file. When I run the below script, nothing is written to the `filecheck_output` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/html/images/
results="$(find projects -name "*.*" | sort -n)"

echo "${results}" > filecheck_output
```

The name of the script is filecheck.  When I remove the `> filecheck_output` section from the end of the script and run `./filecheck > filecheck_output` from the command line, the script runs and outputs the results into the `filecheck_output` file without any issues.

Why will the output only be redirected when I run the command from the command prompt and not from in the script?

Comment: sorry if this is obvious, but are you looking in `/var/www/html/images/` , or your `/home` dir or `/usr/local/bin` or wherever `filecheck` is being stored. It should be in `/var/www/html/images/`. AND be sure  you're not getting a permissions error message when running as a script. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - I think you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is off.  You want to *redirect* output to a file.  To *pipe* something means to take the output from one command and feed it to another, like you are doing in `find | sort`.

Capturing the results in a temporary variable is simply wasteful, so you are really looking just for

```
find projects -name "*.*" | sort -n >filecheck_output
```

The script performs a `cd` earlier on, so the output file will obviously be created in that directory.  If you want to avoid that, either don't `cd`,  or do the `cd` in a subshell.

```
( cd somewhere; find projects ) | sort -n >filecheck_output

find somewhere/projects | sort -n >filecheck_output
```

In the latter case, the output from `find` will include `somewhere` in the path of every generated result.  You can postprocess with `sed` to remove it like I show here, although that seems more brittle than the subshell solution.

```
find somewhere/projects | sed 's%^somewhere/%%' | sort -n
```

Not doing the redirection in the script itself seems like the best way to make it reusable; then you can choose a different output file each time you run it, if you like, so that makes it usable e.g. in a `while` loop over a set of directories, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, you'll want to put the full path, or relative path of filecheck_ouput into your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/html/images/
results="$(find projects -name "*.*" | sort -n)"

echo "${results}" > /home/fedorqui/filecheck_output
```